# My ember application fully reloads when I add a queryParam in a transitionTo()

Tags: ember.js, query-string

I am doing a search based on the data entered by a user in a search form and redirecting to a route with this data as queryParam and this reloads the application completely.

I make the transition like this:
where *'search'* is the data entered by the user

```js
this.get('router').transitionTo('private.route1', { queryParams: { search: search } });
```

In the controller of the destination route I have declared this queryParam

```js
export default Controller.extend({
    queryParams: ['search'],
});
```

and there I do an API search based on this queryParam.
Everything works fine but when I do a `transitionTo()` to this route, for some reason the symbol `'?'` is added at the beginning of the path of my route and this reloads the page.

The result I expected is that the transition is made the url looks like this and the application doesn't fully reload:

```
http://localhost:4200/#/private/route1?search=userdata
```

And the real result is:

```
http://localhost:4200/?#/private/route1?search=userdata
```

with the symbol `'?'` in the beginning of the path, which causes the application to fully reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the code again and again and trying different use cases, I realized that what was happening was not a problem with ember and with its queryParams but in the form where I was obtaining the user data for the search I was doing a native submit and this refreshed the app and added the  '?'  to the beginning of the path.
The solution: in the action for search

```js
actions:{
  search(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // next code....
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you mark this as the correct answer? That was it won't show up in searches as un-answered. Thanks!